# Android SQLite query for rows with distance between my location and a given distance value

Tags: android, sqlite, distance

I have a SQLite database in Android with a table that contains longitude, latitude and other columns.. now I want to get all records that have the distance smaller or equal to a given distance.

For example, I know my current coordinates(lat,long) and I want to get from my table all records that are at the maximum distance of 10km from me.

I found some links on stack but nothing too solid. Is there someone that knows an optimized solution for this problem?

I have thought that I could get all records that have latitude smaller than my lat + distance and greater than my lat - distance and longitude smaller than my long + distance and greater than long - distance. After this query I should check for some unwanted records since the query is not returning only the wanted records..
Is this a good idea?

Comment: This is more of an SQL question than Android. You may have better luck searching for SQL answers, or on Google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do this in two parts,

1) Run a query where you find all records that are within a certain value + or - of the current lat/lng of your location, the where clause might look like:

where (@latitude > (lat - .001) and @latitude > (lat - .001)) and 
      (@longitude> (lng- .001) and @longitude> (longitude- .001))

2) with the rough results from above,  use the great circle/haversine method to determine what the actual distance between each location is (great circle/haversinse is already part of the android maps api).

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, it can be useful.

I don't know what you are trying to do, or if you have a backend or a server. But, if you DO have a server which stores these locations, you can (and should) use MongoDB to store it. It has a great support for geospatial information.

Here is an example of how you do what you want using MongoDB: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-Querying